# 1% values of two columns in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, percentile

my input looks the following,

| SNP | BP | FST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 0.15 |
| 2 | 10 | 0.12 |
| 3 | 15 | 0.03 |
| 4 | 20 | 0.43 |

I'm looking for a straight forward way to get a df with the highest 1% SNP's , means the 1% highest FST values and the corresponding SNP and BP values.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr);df1 %>% slice_max(prop = 0.01, order_by = FST)`

Comment: Or in base R `data[data$FST >= quantile(data$FST, .99), ]`